# Prove that $v_n=\int_{1}^{n}{(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n}} \times \frac{1}{x} \, dx$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

It would be really helpful if anyone would help for this question

We have :

> $$u_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k}}\;\;\;,\;\;\;v_n=ln(n)\,-\,u_n$$

I proved  $\,\forall\,n \ge1 \, ,x>0 $

$\;\;\;\:\:\;\:\:\:\;\;\;\:\:\:\;\;\;\:\:\:\;\;\;\:\:\:1 + ( 1 - \frac{x}{n}) + ...... + ( 1 - \frac{x}{n})^{n-1} = \frac{n}{x}(1-(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n})
\;\;\;\:\:\:$(1) 
( Geometric series)

Now how can we have to prove that :

> $$v_n=\int_{1}^{n}{(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n}}  \times  \frac{1}{x} \, dx$$

using the Lebesgue integral on the interval $[1,n]$ for each part of (1) was a hint that we had but I don't know we can proceed.

Thanks for your help

Edit : Can we conclude that $(v_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ is convergent on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Basically integrate the whole expression (1) over $[1,n]$ as suggested, but divide through by $n$ first. The sum on the left then integrates to $-u_n$. The first term in the integral on the RHS, $\int_1^n \frac{1}{x}dx$, becomes $\ln(n)$, and the second term is the integral you are after (call it $I$).

This gives you $-u_n = \ln(n) - I$, i.e. $v_n = I$.

Comment: Hello @GeorgeDewhirst thanks , could you please  write a complete answer I'm still stuck for the sum I don't find $-u_n$

Comment: Still no clue :\

Comment: oh sorry I'll get right to it.

the integral of $(1)$ from 1 to n gives:

LHS = $-n\sum_{k=0}^n (1-\frac{x}{n})^k = - n u_n$.
RHS = $n(\ln(n) - n v_n)$

Comment: Ouf finally I get that $-nu_n$ thanks a lot @GeorgeDewhirst

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @GeorgeDewhirst but how can we conclude with the result that $(v_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ is convergent ?

Comment: $v_n$ is monotone increasing and is bounded above by $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx<\infty$, thus it is convergent.